# Why this Singleton Pattern doesn't result into StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, singleton

I've recently come across this kind of code somewhere.

```
package com.singleton;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {

        return singleton;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Singleton obj = Singleton.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Done creating Singleton");
    }
}
```

Now, problem in this might not be apparent at first glance. Atleast not to me :p
so, adding this function makes the problem clear enough

```
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Printing inside Singleton Variable");

        singleton.print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Singleton obj = Singleton.getInstance();
        obj.print();
        System.out.println("Done creating Singleton");
    }
```

Now, running the program would result into a `StackOVerflowError`
My question is, There already was this one object inside another kind of pattern in the code. so why it didn't resulted into a StackOverflowError in first case.(i.e. before addition of print function and calling it in main class.)

Comment: In second part of code, you're calling `print` method recursively. What else did you expect? And in the first part of the code, you're not calling any method recursively.

Comment: Why do you think anything the first snippet would case a stack overflow?

Comment: Just because you're returning `singleton` from `getInstance()` doesn't cause any recursive call. If you would have returned `singleton.GetInstance()` then you'll have an overflow as well.

Comment: yes but why object inside the object is not being actually allocated some space in the first case.

Comment: What object inside object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of your confusion is that you think the singleton definition is recursive. It isn't, actually.

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

This is a definition of a *static* field. This means that this field does not exist inside any instance of `Singleton`. It is associated with the `Singleton` class, and initialize at the loading of the class.

If this was not a `static` call, then you would be right. Creating an instance would create a new field which would create a new instance which would create a new field.

But for a static field, initialization is done only once, at the loading of the class. It then calls the constructor of the class, and that's it - no more creations of `Singleton`, no more initialization, and no self-reference.

So this example will cause a `StackOverflowError`:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test test = new Test();

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( new Test() );
    }

}
```

And this is because the field `test` is not `static` but an instance variable, and thus its initialization is done when a new instance is created, and in itself create a new instance and so on.

Change the definition of `test` to static and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Two different scenarios here. Singleton's singleton will be initialized just once when Singleton class itself would get loaded. Hence when you will call getInstance on singleton, it wont reinitialize itself, rather it would return the same instance again and again.

Your second example is a recursive call which call's to itself without any exit condition in it and hence leads to StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

You may also confusing an object relationship that is recursive:

```
class Foo {
    private Foo foo;
    Foo(){ ... }
    public void setFoo( Foo foo ){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

with a dynamic recursion of a method.

There is no problem with classes like Foo if they are constructed without running into a recursion of the other kind, e.g.,

```
Foo(){
    this.foo = new Foo();  // Ooops!
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that in this case the field is static, so it is not even defined recursively inside the object - it is defined at the class level.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well, for completeness' sake, added that, too.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code case, `static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();` was initialized when the Singleton class loaded, every time of calling `Singleton.getInstance();` just returns the variable only.

In the second code case, there exists an `infinite loop call`, This will cause the JVM to allocate stack frames for space indefinitely, and each stack size is limited after allocating, according to the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2)

```
If the computation in a thread requires a larger Java Virtual Machine stack than
is permitted, the Java Virtual Machine throws a StackOverflowError.
```

so this must result in a stackoverflowerror obviously.